# Corners of a custom table view grouped

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uitableview

I am creating a custom tableView with style grouped. My custom cell doesn't adjust with the rounded corners, only when the table is selected.

Any idea why this happens?

Thanks

Comment: How do you do the drawing in the custom cell view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given the limited provided information about how you draw the cells, [here](http://code.coneybeare.net/how-to-make-custom-drawn-gradient-backgrounds) is a blog post that shows a good way of how to do it, along with a gradient background. Basically, you need to draw the corners yourself because iOS wont clip it for you if you override the drawing behavior.

---

*Full Disclosure: It is my code blog.*